# Highlighting text field using the content from another field

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been searching for the answer of this question but I'm not sure if it exists or not in ElasticSearch.

I'm looking for highlight one field using the content of another field.

A simple example here:

```
{
    "title":"This is a test",
    "expressions": "test"
}
```

It's possible to highlight `title` using `expressions` content as a query.

Like:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match": { "content": doc.expressions }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "content" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.. but your query needs to change to something like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match": { "expressions": "test" }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "title" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not exactly what I need, I know how to highlight in the normal way as you pointed. The thing is using another field content to highlight without knowing before highlight what is the content of this field.